# CSS: make an img 100% width unless height exceeds viewport height

Tags: css

My mobile site shows a scrolling column of images which are at 100% width.  However, some images can be taller than the viewport, which is undesirable.  For those images, I want to cap the image height at 100vh and make the width as wide as possible (but necessarily less than 100% when the image is too tall for the viewport), preserving the aspect ratio.

How can I accomplish this with CSS?

Comment: the ratio of the images is the same? known?

Comment: All images are loaded dynamically, so not the same size nor are the ratios known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to force 100% width if possible, but also limit to the viewport height:

```
img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to preserve the aspect ratio, a `max-height` property of `100vh` should work in conjuction with `max-width: 100%`

https://jsfiddle.net/pqn4yx6z/

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work as the images are not 100% width.